# How do I KQL to verify presence of property in child object?

Tags: kql

I have query which returns object below. How do I return results only if `policies` array below contains element with `policyDefinitionId` equal to `somevalue` without using `contains` keyword

```
{
   "isComplianceCheck": "False",
   "resourceLocation": "southcentralus",
   "ancestors": "thc-platform-mg,8f5a5a7f-3cdb-48f1-a894-351a54b84920",
   "policies": "[{\"policyDefinitionId\":\"/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/34f95f76-5386-4de7-b824-0d8478470c9d/\",\"policySetDefinitionId\":\"/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policySetDefinitions/1f3afdf9-d0c9-4c3d-847f-89da613e70a8/\",\"policyDefinitionReferenceId\":\"diagnosticsLogsInLogicAppsMonitoring\",\"policySetDefinitionName\":\"1f3afdf9-d0c9-4c3d-847f-89da613e70a8\",\"policyDefinitionName\":\"34f95f76-5386-4de7-b824-0d8478470c9d\",\"policyDefinitionEffect\":\"AuditIfNotExists\",\"policyAssignmentId\":\"/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/8f5a5a7f-3cdb-48f1-a894-351a54b84920/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments/a45ca010a72c41ceac351431/\",\"policyAssignmentName\":\"a45ca010a72c41ceac351431\",\"policyAssignmentScope\":\"/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/8f5a5a7f-3cdb-48f1-a894-351a54b84920\",\"policyExemptionIds\":[]}]",
   "eventCategory": "Policy",
   "entity": "/subscriptions/3adcdebe-b99e-4781-bcdb-65a58a976594/resourceGroups/thc-man-scus-monitoring-rg/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/this-man-scus-reboot-logic",
   "message": "Microsoft.Authorization/policies/audit/action",
   "hierarchy": "",
   "caller": "me@me.com",
   "eventDataId": "474c5466-033a-4910-90a1-0ce47d80f1c5",
   "eventSubmissionTimestamp": "2021-11-24T15:22:22.7433954Z",
   "httpRequest": "{\"clientIpAddress\":\"47.188.89.222\"}",
   "resource": "this-man-scus-reboot-logic",
   "resourceGroup": "THC-MAN-SCUS-MONITORING-RG",
   "resourceProviderValue": "MICROSOFT.LOGIC",
   "subscriptionId": "3adcdebe-b99e-4781-bcdb-65a58a976594",
   "activityStatusValue": "Success"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
let MyTable = datatable(d:dynamic) [
    dynamic({
       "prop1": "value1",
       "prop2": "value2",
       "policies": "[{\"policyKey1\":\"policyValue1\",\"policyKey2\":\"policyValue2\",\"policyKey3\":\"policyValue3\"},{\"policyKey10\":\"policyValue10\",\"policyKey20\":\"policyValue20\",\"policyKey30\":\"policyValue30\"}]"
    }),
    dynamic({
       "prop1": "value10",
       "prop2": "value20",
       "policies": "[{\"policyKeyA\":\"policyValueA\",\"policyKeyB\":\"policyValueB\",\"policyKeyC\":\"policyValueC\"},{\"policyKeyAA\":\"policyValueAA\",\"policyKeyBB\":\"policyValueBB\",\"policyKeyCC\":\"policyValueCC\"}]"
    }),
    dynamic({
       "prop1": "value100",
       "prop2": "value200",
       "policies": "[{\"policyKeyA\":\"policyValueAA\",\"policyKeyB\":\"policyValueB\",\"policyKeyC\":\"policyValueC\"},{\"policyKeyAA\":\"policyValueAA\",\"policyKeyBB\":\"policyValueBB\",\"policyKeyCC\":\"policyValueCC\"}]"
    }),
];
MyTable
| mv-apply policy = todynamic(tostring(d.policies)) on
(
    mv-expand policy
    | where policy['policyKeyA'] == 'policyValueA'
)
| project-away policy
```

Result:

| d |
| --- |
| { "prop1": "value10", "prop2": "value20", "policies": "[{"policyKeyA":"policyValueA","policyKeyB":"policyValueB","policyKeyC":"policyValueC"},{"policyKeyAA":"policyValueAA","policyKeyBB":"policyValueBB","policyKeyCC":"policyValueCC"}]" } |

**Explanation:**

you'll need to use two tricks to solve this one:

1. You need to use [`mv-apply`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mv-applyoperator) in order to iterate over all the items in the `policy` object, and then filter for the exact policy you're looking for (for example, `| where policy['policyKeyA'] == 'policyValueA'`).
2. Because the value of `policies` isn't really a json, but rather a **string** that represents a json, and because when extracting from a **dynamic** object you get a dynamic object as well - you can't just iterate over `d.policies` - you'll need to first convert this from dynamic to string, and then create a dynamic from this string, like this: `todynamic(tostring(d.policies))`